# CXF X509 Webservice Request Verification For The Certifcate Alias

Tags: web-services, cxf

I need to do the verification of CXF X509 webservice request for the certificate alias.

### Issue:

Need to verify the incoming webservice request which has WS-security in place.
I want to verify the request on the basis of the alias of the certificate that was used for WS-security of the webservice.

Can some one provide some inputs on this . Also can we achieve this using the CXF configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to configure the above identification of request on the basis of the certificate.

### Scenario:

1. Webservice request with CXF X509 Ws-security implemented.
2. The request is encrypted and signed both.
3. The client private key has alias 'ABC' and the server public key has the alias 'XYZ'.

### Solution

1. Implement the interceptor for validation
2. The interceptor be extending AbstractPhaseInterceptor.
3. The phase of interceptor will be PRE_INVOKE
4. Define the interceptor bean in the application context
5. Create class with for extracting the alias using the org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin.
6. Just verify the alias and throw proper response.